# use values from a column as index to extract a value from another column in R

Tags: r, indexing, tidyverse

Suppose I have this dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data_frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(21:30), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 8, 3, NA, 4, 7, 3)) 

       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1    21    NA
 2     2    22    NA
 3     3    23    NA
 4     4    24     1
 5     5    25     8
 6     6    26     3
 7     7    27    NA
 8     8    28     4
 9     9    29     7
10    10    30     3
```

I want to use the non-NA values in column C as index to extract the values in column B to create a new column D. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
      A     B     C     D
   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    21    NA    NA
 2     2    22    NA    NA
 3     3    23    NA    NA
 4     4    24     1    21
 5     5    25     8    28
 6     6    26     3    23
 7     7    27    NA    NA
 8     8    28     4    24
 9     9    29     7    27
10    10    30     3    23
```

I tried `df %>% mutate(D = df[C,])` and `df %>% mutate(D = df[C,B])` but both code doesn't give me the result I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index `B` using `C`

```
transform(df, D = B[C])
```

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(D = B[C])

# A tibble: 10 x 4
#       A     B     C     D
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1    21    NA    NA
# 2     2    22    NA    NA
# 3     3    23    NA    NA
# 4     4    24     1    21
# 5     5    25     8    28
# 6     6    26     3    23
# 7     7    27    NA    NA
# 8     8    28     4    24
# 9     9    29     7    27
#10    10    30     3    23
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
df$D <- with(df, B[C])
```